# Creating a sidebar using Flex in React but centering the content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a UI with header and a sidebar.

My `App` component looks like

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div className="App">
          <SubHeader/>
          <Container className="container-comp"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The style for `App` is

```
.App {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

and my `SubHeader` which is the sidebar looks like

```
const SubHeader = () => {
    return (
        <div id="sidebar">
            <div className="logo-container">
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

where `sidebar` style is

```
   #sidebar {
     width: 12em;
     background: #39393b;
   }
```

This looks like (please ignore the pen scribble)

[image]

I want to keep the sidebar in that position, but want to center my component (console).

I tried to do

```
.App {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[image]

but it centers everything including the sidebar.

How can I make this work?

Thanks

**render**

```
class Container extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.className}>
                <h3>Show Console</h3>
                <ServerCard />
                <RouterCard />
                <CommandCard />
                <LocationCard />
                <div>
                    <Button
                        className="submit-button"
                        onClick={this.runCommands}>
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    {this.renderStatus()}
                    {this.renderLoc()}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You `SubHeader` component is wrapped within the `.App`. So Applying any `CSS` to `.App` will also get applied to `SubHeader` component.

If you only want to center the element of `Container` component, you need to apply `CSS` to `.container-comp` like,

```
.container-comp{
   text-align:center;
}
```

---

**Update**

It looks like `Container` is your custom component like `SubHeader` component. You need to assign class name `container-comp` passed as `props` to parent div of `Container` component like this,

```
const Container = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={props.className} >  // here props.className = container-comp
            <div>
              console
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

**Update 2**

As you are using `display:flex`, your custom `Container` component is not taking extire space available. You just need to add `flex-grow:1` to take entire available space.

```
.container-comp{
   text-align:center;
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rpqvmn)

Comment: Thanks but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Is Container is custom component? If yes then add this class to parent div of that element and it will work.

Comment: Can you post your Container comonent?

Comment: I posted the render part of the Container